# Adding an observer to a UISwitch within a custom tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift

This is a follow on from a previous question I have asked but I feel I am missing something very simple and its driving me up the wall!

I have a custom tableview cell which contains a switch and I need to trigger a function each time it's value is changed. I've tried using `.addTarget` but it never seems to trigger the function so maybe my selector syntax is incorrect.
I create the switch programatically within the tableview cell like this:

```
let thisSwitch: UISwitch = {
    let thisSwitch = UISwitch()
    thisSwitch.isOn = false
    thisSwitch.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    thisSwitch.addTarget(self, action: Selector("switchTriggered:"), for: .valueChanged)
    return thisSwitch

}()
```

Then directly below that I have my function:

```
func switchTriggered(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("SWITCH TRIGGERED")
    let sentSwitch = sender as! UISwitch
    privateExercise.switchState = sentSwitch.isOn

}
```

It shows an error message stating " No method declared with Objective-C selector 'switchTriggered:' ". What am I missing here? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The selector syntax should be

```
thisSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchTriggered), for: .valueChanged)
```

Also keep the parameter as `UISwitch` type itself in order to avoid casting in function

```
func switchTriggered(sentSwitch: UISwitch) {
    print("SWITCH TRIGGERED")
    privateExercise.switchState = sentSwitch.isOn
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply.
I've just tried this and although the error message is gone, it still doesn't seem to trigger my function.
Just for reference, in my exercise variable there is a switchState variable which should keep track of the switch, hence the need for the action.
Do you have any ideas as to why it's not calling the method?

Comment: Are you adding this switch button somewhere?
Please post your complete cellForRow code

Comment: First of all please post the code in question by editing, secondly where is the part the UISwitch is added to the UITableViewCell's view.  The configureCellWith function body is missing.

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        var thisCell = UITableViewCell()
        
        if tableView == self.tableView {
            let aCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "thirdCellID", for: indexPath) as! exerciseCell
            aCell.configureCellWith(exercise: mobilityExercises[indexPath.row])
            aCell.excersiseLabel.text = "\(mobilityExercises[indexPath.row].exerciseName!)"
            thisCell = aCell
        }
        return thisCell
        
    }

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how to create code blocks in a comment. 

I'm adding the switch using a method within the custom tableview cell. I just use addSubview(thisSwitch) within a method that then does all of the constraints using visual formatting

Comment: Where is the `addSubview` part of your UISwitch and what is the parent view

Comment: It's in a function that is called when the custom cell is initialised. It's parent view is the tableview cell I believe

Comment: Please post the complete flow code otherwise it is very hard to understand.
The switch adding statement should be in cellForRow and it should be separated by some sort of tag as indexPath.row.